# Open source patents?

Tags: open-release

I would like to be able to patent the design for an apparatus I made, I don't care about royalties I just want to spread the idea in a citable way that can't be patented by someone else for profit.
Is there an easier way to do this than a regular patent? 
I live in Europe.

I'd appreciate any advice, thanks!

Comment: Since you asked specifically for an **alternative** to a patent, I cited the question linked in the duplicate. But if you are interested in a public release *with* patent protection, see :  **[Can an idea be released into the public domain while patent is pending?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/19410/can-an-idea-be-released-into-the-public-domain-while-patent-is-pending)**

Comment: Here are more ways to protect ideas for public use *without* patent protection — **[Do patentless idea implementations published on a web site enter the public domain?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/12088/do-patentless-idea-implementations-published-on-a-web-site-enter-the-public-doma)**

Comment: Utility models are comparably cheap. If you don't care about protection, that might be an idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot, utility models seem to be the easiest way to do this. The other alternative I see is to publish the work in a technical journal then it's not patent-able for anyone else.